# 'Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_FollowRedirects(Boolean)'

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

Using Smartsheet-csharp sdk , It was working fine with RestSharp 106.15.0.
When updated RestSharp to latest version 108.01 its giving error on following line of code

```
SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(accessToken).Build();
```

> Error: System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void
> RestSharp.RestClient.set_FollowRedirects(Boolean)'.'